# Grab the contents on screen painted via OpenGL

Tags: opengl, quartz-graphics

I want to know if its possible to grab the contents of screen/surface painted via OpenGL? and how to do it?

I mean something like this (From Quarzt), If I have CGBitmapContextRef, I can do all the drawing activity on it and then create a CGBitmap out of it. Is there something similar? If not please suggest some different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for this you have to use [glReadPixels](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml), but you should notice that heavy use of this function can be slow.